# 404 when calling Imgur OAuth2 API

Tags: oauth-2.0, imgur

First attempt at using the Imgur API for OAuth2 authentication.  I have a Client ID and Client Secret from https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient.  The URL that is being called from my Vue application looks like:
`https://api.imgur.com/oath2/authorize?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&response_type=token&state=test`

...where `{CLIENT_ID}` is the Client ID obtained from the client registration.  This doesn't work from my web app and also fails in Postman.  I'm getting back a 404 which displays the page that reads, "Zoinks! You've taken a wrong turn."
Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. For me the solution was to open my Vue application from the network address `https://192.168.2.100:8080` instead of the local adress `https://localhost:8080`

[Vue console picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHsvm.png)

Imgur apparently doesn't accept requests from localhost. Consequently I also had to set the OAuth2 redirect url of my application [registered in imgur](https://imgur.com/account/settings/apps) to `http://192.168.2.100:8080/...`